# Haskell alternative to SDL for windows

Tags: image, haskell, graphics

Due to the various issues with getting hsSDL to work on Windows, I'm looking for another library that can handle keyboard input and drawing images to the screen. Does anyone know of any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've successfully used [gloss](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss) on Windows in the past without issues. It's also very simple (which I like) and is my go-to recommendation for people who want to use Haskell for simple graphics/ basic games.

Edit: It looks like gloss is having issues building on the Hackage server and as a result isn't displaying documentation. [Here is the documentation for version 1.8.1.2](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-1.8.1.2), which should be about the same.

Comment: Does gloss allow for drawing images, or just simple primitives? -nevermind, just checked for myself

Comment: @StupidQuestions It supports Bitmaps, via BitmapData: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-1.8.1.2/docs/Graphics-Gloss-Data-Picture.html#t:BitmapData and loadBMP: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-1.8.1.2/docs/Graphics-Gloss-Data-Picture.html#v:loadBMP